# Short story where a scientist discovers all the secrets of the universe as he is dying

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story around 3 years ago, but it might have been written much earlier.

The premise of the story is this: A scientist has spent his whole life researching some aspect of the universe but is never able to find what he wants to. But when he's dying, his soul (?) discovers all the secrets of the universe. Then he is reborn and still rememebers everything he discovered while he was dying.

As a toddler, he tries to tell these things to his parents and people around him, but they only find his words cute as they are unable to understand him. As he grows up, he slowly loses his knowledge about the universe and it's completely gone by the time he is able to talk.

Does anyone know what the story is called?

---

I posted this question on [reddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/8zhjco/tomt_looking_for_a_short_story_where_a_scientist/) and a user there commented:

> *I’ve read this story on tumblr.com. It had an image of a galaxy accompanying it. Tried to find it, but tumblrs search function is either terrible or I don’t understand how it works.*

Maybe that can help jog someone's memory?

Comment: I seem to remember something similar where he remembered everything in the womb, but forgot it due to the trauma of birth. Someone remarks that the new-born looks, like all babies do, like an old man, but that the wrinkles smooth over rapidly.

Comment: @ths : This sounds similar to Damon Knight's "Special Delivery" (1954), where a superintelligent fetus controls his mother from the womb but loses his special powers upon birth, when he becomes an ordinary "red, wrinkled, puny" baby.

Comment: It doesn't match, but this reminds me of chapter 5 in *Mary Poppins Comes Back* by P. L. Travers.  That chapter describes the newborn child Annabel Banks as knowing certain secrets of how she came into being and can communicate with animals, but loses this ability in a few weeks.  No scientist or reincarnation though.

Comment: That was an interesting read @user14111. But sadly, no, that's not it.